# react-router-dom NavLink doesn't reflect isActive change without refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, connected-react-router

I'm trying to use the `NavLink`'s `isActive` prop to check whether the link's route is the current route to apply some visual styling.

Whenever I navigate to a page it works correctly as expected. However, if I tap a link while I'm inside a page, the changes aren't reflected to the components. The page and the address (which I presume is using `history.pushState`, which might be the culprit) updates instantly (without an actual HTTP page reload) but the old page still has the `isActive` property and the new one doesn't.

If I refresh the page which performs an actual "hard" reload, then the change is reflected.

Here is the relevant parts of the code (with actual paths anonymized) (`styles` is my imported module CSS with the relevant styles):

```
function NavigationBar(props:NavigationBarProps){
    return <div className={styles['container']}>
        <NavLink to={'/first'} className={props => `${styles['link']} ${props.isActive ? styles['selected'] : ''}`}>
            first
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to={'/second'} className={props => `${styles['link']} ${props.isActive ? styles['selected'] : ''}`}>
            second
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to={'/third'} className={props => `${styles['link']} ${props.isActive ? styles['selected'] : ''}`}>
            third
        </NavLink>
    </div>
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get it to work correctly (without implementing path changes manually and without disabling using history API, of course)?

I am on React 18.0.1, React-DOM 18.1.0, React-Router 6.3.0, React-Router-DOM 6.3.0 and connected-react-router 6.9.2.

**UPDATE:** I've also tried ditching `connected-react-router` (as it's suggested that it doesn't fully support `react-router` 6.x and seems like a dead library) and moving completely to https://github.com/salvoravida/redux-first-history yet still have the exact same problem.

**UPDATE 2:** This problem seems to be happening on Safari. It works correctly on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino I've added the code to the question.

Comment: have you checked this? https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/active-navlink-inline-styles-with-react-router

Comment: AFAIK `connected-react-router` hasn't been updated yet to be compatible with `react-router-dom@6`.

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino the example is exactly doing what I'm doing (just using inline styles instead of CSS classes, otherwise the same logic)

Comment: @DrewReese I've switched to `redux-first-history` (as many commented out at the issues), yet _still_ have the same problem.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code attempt that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @Drew Reese makes a good point. It's best to have a live version of your code with the same behavior as in your project that we can debug.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this example [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-mestorf-dzfmh0?file=/src/App.js:344-466)

Comment: are you implying to put links directly under `BrowserRouter` or not using styles and relying on browser's default link styles? don't know how I can pull the first one without heavy refactoring, and second one isn't possible as I don't want the default styles. otherwise, my code is the same as the in the sandbox if I'm not missing something.

Comment: I suggest put your NavLink groups to the BrowserRouter,  after that if it is possible use styles, if it will be huge refactoring , then don't pass  props to the className function ,  passing object to the className function , in the ES6 template literals can be undefined , if props will be undefined also , check this example [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-mestorf-dzfmh0?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I have a check your example again , and use same in my example with className and object property , inside of  BrowserRouter , objects is okay for you. @CanPoyrazoğlu , but anyway try to check is styles['link'] it come true or not , or sometimes is true sometimes is undefined, I am not sure

Comment: Debug it `${styles['link']} ${props.isActive ? styles['selected'] : ''}` and check is everyting consoled fine as you want , use my example , try to console

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with my styles, when I refresh the page it works just fine. It also works fine on Chrome and Firefox. The problem is with Safari and only when I use a NavLink that uses history API instead of a full page load, so that's very likely about it.